# Change checkbox icon color on hover and checked

Tags: html, css

I need to change the icon color in the checkbox on hover and on checked, simultaniously.

I have this code for a checkbox:

`&:checked:hover + label::before { border: none; color: blue; }`

And the behaviour I expected was: when the user hovers and the checkbox is checked, the icon changes the color. However this does not seem to work.

Comment: Could you share the HTML code as well so people can help you

Comment: Please include a complete example including the HTML and CSS (Your current selector looks like a CSS preprocessed language like LESS, since it starts with an `&`)

Comment: Welcome to SO, please could you edit your question and use the snippet button to include your html and create a [mcve] otherwise we will be unable to help you

Answer (score 1):

You need to put your code up but given that you're using the adjacent sibling combinator, it look as though your icon is after your checkbox but is missing the :hover pseudo class, e.g as follows.

```css
#myInput:checked+label:hover::before {
  color: blue;
}

label::before {
  content: "✖";
  margin-right: 0.5rem;
}
```

```html
<input type=checkbox id='myInput'>
<label for='myInput'>Label</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the new CSS accent-color property to change the background colour of the checkbox:

```
input[type='checkbox'] {
accent-color: red;
```

}